# MySQL "non unique id"

Tags: mysql

I have a special ID column in a MySQL database. Some of the rows have the same special ids. Is there a way, when I'm selecting data, to specify if I've already grabbed a row with that special id to ignore the next row with that same special id?

Comment: One problem is that rows in the database aren't actually stored in any particular order. Think from the database's point of view: which row do you want it to return, if there are multiple?

Comment: Yea, I see the point heh, but at this point I wouldn't mind selecting the first row with the id. I suppose I will have to do it with php...

Comment: @Dalton Conley - You can do it via SQL. You just have to get out of your head the concept of "first". Rows are unordered sets of data. So, if given a bag of rows for a given SpecialId, how do you choose which one to keep? One way is to arbitrarily choose based on the lowest PK value or highest PK value or some other criteria.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for wording it better. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't give us much to go on (such as schema, sample inputs, expected outputs etc), however, what you seek might entail something akin to:

```
Select ....
From MyTable
    Join    (
            Select Min( PrimarykeyColumn ) As Pk
                , SpecialId
            From MyTable
            Group By SpecialId
            ) As SpecialIdValues
        On SpecialIdValues.Pk = MyTable.PrimarykeyColumn
```

In this scenario, I'm arbitrarily chosing the lowest Primary Key value for each of the SpecialId values.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting one exemplar from each group is a difficult problem. There are solutions discussed [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104) and [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). Also see [this thread](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209383) on the MySQL discussion list.